# Operations on a column of data involving data from other columns

Tags: list-manipulation

Say, I have two columns of data, viz., A and B. I would like to make a data set with column A data converted to A/(B-1/B^2) (cell wise), and Column B converted to 1/B (cell wise) using a line of code. Can some one please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica, you can treat columns as single variable. So all what you have to do is type exactly what you have. No changes needed

```
A0 = {a1, a2, a3};
B0 = {b1, b2, b3};
A0/(B0 - 1/B0^2)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
1/B0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention data set, I will give an approach using [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset). Here is a random [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset) of data:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Dataset @ Table[
    AssociationThread[{"A","B","C"},RandomInteger[{2,5},3]],
    {4}
]
```

[image]

To create a new dataset using your conversions you could do:

```
data[All, <|"New A" -> Query[#A/(#B-1/#B^2)&], "New B" -> Query[1/#B^2&]|>]
```

[image]